# Do Agnes, Margo and Edith from Despicable Me have the same parents?

Tags: plot-explanation, despicable-me

All three girls have the same stepparents Gru and Lucy, but are they true sisters? I mean, do they have the same biological mother and/or father?

Comment: The phrase "true sisters" may be ambiguous: it could mean just full biological sisters (both the same mother and father) or half-sisters (they only share a mother or father) as well as sisters. I'm being pedantic, since your question's "and/or" probably covers this, but I figured I'd make the note in case you wanted to make the distinction explicitly.

Comment: Same question asked at [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/94561/31394).

Answer (score 27):

From this [answer by Valorum at SF & F](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94561/were-agnes-edith-and-margo-legally-sisters-prior-to-their-adoption)

> The [script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Despicable-Me-2.html) for Despicable Me 2 identifies them as sisters:
>
> > **MARGO:** *Uh, sure. I'm...Margo.*
> >
> > They begin walking away together, then **Margo is reminded of her sisters when Edith loudly clears her throat.**
>
> However, it doesn't confirm whether they're sisters as a result of
> Gru's adoption or that they were legally sisters before that.
>
> ---
>
> The official *[Despicable Me: The Junior Novel](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Despicable-Me-The-Junior-Novel/dp/0316083801)* identifies that
> they **aren't** sisters by birth:
>
> > Meanwhile, in another part of town, the three little girls arrive home. Or at least it’s their home for now. Miss Hattie’s Home for
> > Girls is the name of the orphanage where Margo, Edith, and Agnes live.
> > They wish every day for a nice family to come and adopt each of them.
>
> > **They aren’t technically sisters, but they spend all their time together.** Margo is the oldest, Agnes is the youngest, and Edith is
> > the messiest.
>
> Once again, they're referred to as sisters in *[Despicable Me 2: The
> Junior Novel](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Despicable-Me-The-Junior-Novel/dp/031623432X)* (written by the same author), lending credence to
> the suggestion that they weren't legally sisters until *after* Gru had
> adopted them:
>
> > All the kids turn to see Gru’s pet dressed as a dragon. His name is Kyle, and he has long, spiky teeth. Kyle is not thrilled to play the
> > part of the dragon and grumbles, causing the kids to scream and huddle
> > around Agnes.
> >
> > Then Agnes’s oldest sister, Margo, comes out dressed as Joan of Arc. She is wearing a suit of armor and carrying a mighty sword.

Comment: If you are upvoting this question, please consider upvoting the original source at SF&F

Answer (score 10):

While there is no clear mention about their biological parents in the movies, I found [this](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Fridge/DespicableMe) article where they claim

> If you notice carefully, that the girls were never referred to as "sisters" in the first film by each other or even Miss Hattie. It's a subtle clue that Margo, Edith, and Agnes are not blood related siblings...

So, I guess they are not *true sisters*.